# Cannot read property .toLowerCase() of undefined: aki-api

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a `Discord.Js` bot that has an "Akinator" command.
After finding a suitable package ([aki-api](https://github.com/jgoralcz/aki-api#readme)) and running it I get this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

The error originates from this function `aki.start()` and I don't understand why it originates here.

Here's some more code

```
const { Aki } = require('aki-api');
...
const aki = new Aki(region); // ERROR ORIGINATES HERE
```

Comment: Most obvious reason for the error is that the value  of `region` is undefined. Have you tried to log it out before passing it to the Aki function??

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Ok will do

Comment: Ok so if you actualy have a look at the documentation you would find out that the first and only param the Aki constructor takes is an object like this { region: ... } and you are passing in a string.

Comment: Oh ty i hope by adding {} will work thx @Molda

edit : worked